# fixing apache v9.0 Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start error

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jakarta-mail

i have a simple java ee project which i need to send an email to a user, i found that it is possible with javamail and the gmail free smtp.

my mail sender implementation:

```
package duck.reg.pack;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

@WebServlet("/sendmailtls")
public class SendMailTLS extends HttpServlet {
public static void main(){

final String username = "john.fob@gmail.com";
final String password = "Password";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
});

try {

    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("joh.fob@gmail.com"));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        InternetAddress.parse("jon.fob@yahoo.com"));
    message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
    message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
        + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

    Transport.send(message);

    System.out.println("Done");

} catch (MessagingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
}
```

now the problem is that when ever i compile my program i get apache error saying:

> 'Starting tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem.
>   Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

and i found that if i remove

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
}
});
```

it compile just fine.

Comment: Failing to compile your web application and failing to start your Tomcat server are two different problems.  How are you compiling your program and how are you starting Tomcat?  Are you using an IDE that does "compile and deploy" with one button press?  How have you added JavaMail to your project?  Did you put the jar file somewhere?  Did you add a Maven dependency?

Comment: it is not about the compilation actually, i mean when ever i have the `session session...` in my code i can't even just restart my apache server it self, and i have the javamail at my project directory in a folder called lib

Comment: Obviously you're doing something wrong but you haven't provided us enough detail about exactly what you're doing for us to help you.  How do you compile your application?  Does the compilation succeed?  How do you package your application (e.g., in a war file)?  How do you deploy your application to your Tomcat server?  How do you stop and restart your Tomcat server?  Is your Tomcat server running on the same machine you use to compile your application?  Exactly where have you put the JavaMail jar file?

Answer (score 4):

If there is a error in the project web.xml file (Not the server web.xml file) it prevents the starting the server starting.check and verify the web.xml and other xml files related to the project. For me when i fix the errors in web xml file server ran correctly.sometimes the server cache shows the previous errors in web pages which you are developing.beware of that also.

Answer (score 1):

Apache server normally runs on port 8080 and this port might be busy so try to free that port .
First find that which all process are running on port 8080 through cmd ,
 command to find is

netstat -ano find "8080"

It will list the PID and using that PID kill that process through cmd,
command to kill process is

taskkill /f /pid PIDno

Comment: i actually have changed my apache to use port 30012 and there is nothing that is using port 8080

Comment: So find out which process are running on port 30012

Comment: if apache is not running then nothing is using it, just checked it is totally empty

Comment: Suppose you are running an application on Apache tomcat server in IDE and you close the IDE without stopping the Apache server or your PC gets shut down in that case , Apache tomcat still holds that port in background and never frees that port and in that case when ever you try to run tomcat you get such error

Comment: but i just tried cmd `netstat -a -n -o | findstr 0.0:30012` command and i got nothing that would use it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case a a jar in .m2 folder was corrupted. I deleted it and did a maven install . It downloaded the jar again and this time my server was able to build

Answer (score 1):

```
kindly check all xml files again and cross check whether they are dependent on each other ,remove that all dependency or fix that dependency and after that follow the following steps 

1>right click project name
2>Run on server 
3>select installed tomcat version
4>then next 
5>remove all project from right side box 
6>keep only which u want to run
7>finish
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and i noticed that beneath the nav bar the button 'terminate' was coloured in red. I clicked it then the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

web.xml is the culprit here most of the time.

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Copy paste the content in your web.xml file

If you have defined "`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`" by mistake remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the all @WebServlet annotations.
Use web.xml file to handle the all mappings.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>xxx</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>xxx.xxx.xxx</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>xxx</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/xxxxx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change tomcat port, go to server tab on eclipse, right click->Open then change Tomcat admin port and HTTP/1.1 port, they are probably used somewhere else.